# Limit mod_security rule to one vhost only

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, mod-security, domain

I run several domains (via vhosts) with the same apache installation. Some domains require different mod_security rules than the others. In a seperate exceptions.conf file I collect all those rules and have this syntax:

```
<Location "/test">
    SecAuditEngine Off
    SecRuleRemoveById 950134
    SecRuleRemoveById 981265
    SecRuleRemoveById 981289
    SecRuleRemoveById 981244
    SecAuditEngine RelevantOnly     
</Location>
```

But this rule would match all /test folders on all domains! But I only want to limit it to a specific host. How can I limit those rules to a vhost only in a global exceptions.conf file?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some different ways to do that:

- instead of having a global exception file, put the exceptions inside the virtual host definitions
- if you want to have an exception file separate from the actual virtual host definition, don't include it in the main server config - instead include it from inside the virtual host.
- instead of using `<Location>`, use SecRule and the `ctl:ruleRemoveByID` action. Example:

`SecRule SERVER_NAME "somedomain\.com$" "@streq /test/.*" "ctl:ruleRemoveByID=981244"`

If possible, the first one would be by far the simplest.

Comment: How would I set a different SecResponseBodyLimit?

Comment: `"@streq /test/.*"` is seems too much, results into: `SecRule takes two or three arguments, rule target, operator and optional action list`.